# plot dataframe with datetime as index and only display hours, minutes, and seconds on x-axis in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, x-axis

I am able to produce the following plot with this code:

```py
df_day['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_day['Time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
df_day = df_day.set_index('Time')

fig=plt.figure(dpi=900)
plt.title("TESTER Summary for Day %i " %y + "\n Average Chamber Pressure %.3f [torr] \n" %p_avg_temp  + str(dates[x]))

ax1 = df_day['DP-2'].plot(label = 'DP-2')
ax2 = df_day['FM-1'].plot(secondary_y = True, label = "Flow Rate")

ax1.set_ylabel('Temperatures - Pressure Drop\nInlet Pressure - Scale Weight')

ax2.set_ylabel('Flow Rate - Heat Rej.')

ax1.set_xlabel('Time ')

handles,labels = [],[]
for ax in fig.axes:
    for h,l in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels()):
        handles.append(h)
        labels.append(l)

plt.legend(handles, labels, loc = 'lower center', bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, -0.5), ncol = 3)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.25)

ax1.grid(True, linestyle = ':')
ax2.grid(True, linestyle = ':')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I don't want the date to show up in the xtick labels. I want hours, minutes and seconds. I have also tried:

```py
df_day['Time'] = pd.Series([val.time() for val in df_day['Time']])
```

instead of

```py
df_day['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_day['Time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

but then I get

[image]

and the time intervals are arbitrary and don't include seconds when the seconds are 00.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this lines before you code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S') # here you can format your datetick labels as desired
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

And look at this post [plot_date function set xticks for hourly data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729169/plot-date-function-set-xticks-for-hourly-data)